# Function unresolved reference in main activity

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx

so I'll try to explain my problem this time without pasting you 400 lines of code.

I have a custom view that im using in my main activity (com.company.app.common.ui.view1), in my main activity it's imported properly as follow
`import com.company.app.common.ui.view1`

Inside view1 i have a function defined in the constructor
`fun updateItems(items: List<Item>){}`

Item is an object I have modeled properly and the function has no errors.

But when I try to call it in my main activity using
`view1.updateItems(items)` I get an unresolved reference on `updateItems`.

the function is supposedly public by default if im not wrong, can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: oo I'd like to add that im trying to call updateItems INSIDE a function in mainActivity, I think that's related to my issue but idk the workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to call the method on class rather than on instance (one way to get an instance is to create it via constructor `myView1 = view1(...)` and then you can call the method on it `myView1.updateItems(items)`

Two more points:

- No need to post all code, just post snippets (only the code relevant to the issue), replace the non-relevant code with `...` and keep the parenthesis
- In my answer I assumed (based on what you wrote) that `view1` is supposed to be a class/object, it's good practice to capitalize it's name so it does not get confused with instances

Comment: You were right, I was trying to run the function on the class, instead I should have invoked it on the id of the view that instantiated it in my activity's xml, works now, thanks!